# How can I route to a new page using tabController?

Tags: dart, flutter

Sorry if this sounds a bit obvious but this framework is still fairly unknown to me but I have created a bunch of other pages in my app (saved as .dart files) and also have created paths to them through the use of a drawer. I now have have a bottomNavigationBar that has 5 tabs. I want to be able to route to my previously created page using the tabs. I am currently using the defaultTabController.

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(  
    color: Colors.grey[200],  
        child: Container(  
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),   
                child: TabBar(  
                    isScrollable: true  
                    labelColor: Colors.black,  
                    labelPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(21, 0, 21, 16),  
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black45,  
                    indicatorColor: Colors.orange,  
                    indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(21, 0, 21, 16),  
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(  
                        fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold  
                    ),  
                 tabs: <Tab>[  
                    new Tab(  
                       text: "Home",  
                   ),  
                    new Tab(  
                       text: "Page 1",  
                   ),  
                    new Tab(  
                       text: "Page 2",  
                   ),  
                    new Tab(  
                       text: "Page 3",  
                   ),  
                    new Tab(  
                       text: "Page 4",  
                ),  
              ],  
            ),  
          ),  
       ),
```

For example, when someone clicks on the "Page 1" tab, I want to be able to route the user to my "page1.dart" file. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `TabBar` if you're using `bottomNavigationBar`. You can implement bottomNavigationBar by code below.

```
  int currentIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> children = [
    Home();
    Page1();
  ];

  onTapped(int index){
    setState(() {
      currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          onTap: onTapped,
            currentIndex: currentIndex,
            items: [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add), title: Text('Page 1'))
            ]),
        body: children[currentIndex]);
  }
```

`currentIndex` will keep the record of the current opened tab. `children` is the List of pages you want to route in body. `onTapped` will change `currentIndex` to index of Navigation Bar.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was wondering how to do this without icons and just words for the tabs (see example above). Maybe it's just my inexperience but the BottomNavigationBarItem seems to need an icon assigned to it and I can't manage to get around that?